# sample code to parse data through JSON in android

Tags: android, json

I want to parse REST Webservices with the help of JSON. Plz help me by giving sample code how to parse the rest webservices xml in android through JSON

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of JSON parsing if it is what you need, for parsing a JSON file containing contacts :

```
List<Contact> result = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    try {
        // Creation a the http client to connect to the url and get the json
        // file
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlContacts);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        // json file returned as a string
        jStringContacts = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        jsonContacts = new JSONObject(jStringContacts);
        JSONObject contactsObject = jsonContacts.getJSONObject("contacts");
        JSONArray jsonContactsArray = contactsObject.getJSONArray("contact");
        // loop to extract one contact from the JSON Array
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonContactsArray.length(); i++) {
            jsonContact = jsonContactsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.firstname = jsonContact.getString("firstname");
            contact.lastname = jsonContact.getString("lastname");
            contact.iconName = jsonContact.getString("profileImageName");
            contact.isZenika = "1".equals(jsonContact.getString("zenika"));
            contact.biography = jsonContact.getString("shortBio");
            result.add(contact);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just now imlement....

Step1:Create A main class activity..

class main{
///call method parse();
ParserHelper ob=new ParseHelper(this,Arraylist from parse())
}

```
public ArrayList<String> parse(){
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        URL twitter = new URL("http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json");
        URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) 
            {
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                if(jo.getString("text")!=null)
                listItems.add(jo.getString("text"));
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Step:2 Create class to inflate it to Main list
public class JsonHelper extends BaseAdapter{

```
Activity a;
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

private static LayoutInflater inflate=null;

JsonHelper(Activity a,ArrayList<String> list){
    this.a=a;
    this.list=list;
    inflate=(LayoutInflater) a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    list.size();
}
@Override
public int getCount() {

    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    TextView txt1;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View v=convertView;
   ViewHolder vh;

   if(convertView==null){
       v=inflate.inflate(R.layout.simplelistitem,null);
    vh=new ViewHolder();
    vh.txt1=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    v.setTag(vh);
   }
   else{
  vh=(ViewHolder) v.getTag();
   }
   vh.txt1.setText(list.get(position).toString());
   return v;
}
```

}