# Convert JSON data into an associative array

Tags: java, android, json, getjson

I have an app that does some authentication using Google Accounts. As a response to my request , Google sends the following JSON

`{
 "id": "ID",
 "name": "NAME",
 "given_name": "GiVEN NAME",
 "family_name": "FAMILY_NAME",
 "link": "https://plus.google.com/ID",
 "picture": "https://PHOTO.jpg",
 "gender": "GENDER",
 "locale": "LOCALE"
}`

The problem is that many google accounts don't have all those details filled out. So in most cases the JSON looks like

{ "id": "ID",
 "locale": "LOCALE"
}

So in order to get the data I need, I need to check each JSON to see if the name,picture,gender etc. are provided and if not, prompt the user to enter those data items.To do this I tried checking if the JSONObject.getString("name") etc. was **null**. But instead of completing the if condition, the app skips to an JSON exception.

So what I need is a way to add the JSON data Google sends me to an Associative Array with the keys and values and check through that array to see if the data I need is there without getting an JSON exception.Do you know any way of doing that?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: see following link http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: You seem to have some problems with some code that you have written, but your description of your problem doesn't make much sense.  Please include the relevant part of the code AND the exception message and stack trace for the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that using:

```
if(JSONObject.has("name"))
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: Yeah it seems to work very well.thank you.I've marked this as the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`JSONObject.optString(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString%28java.lang.String%29)

```
if ( "".equals( jsonObject.optString("name") ) ) {
    // name is not present
}
```

As per Javadoc:

> public String optString (String name)
>
> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists, coercing it if
>   necessary. Returns the empty string if no such mapping exists.

Answer (score 0):

> see the answer at stack-over flow:
>   [JSON to multidimentional array in android/java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936022/json-to-multidimentional-array-in-android-java)
>
> hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

To check if JSON has specific field use

```
jsonObject.has("NAME")
```

if it returns **true** simply add this field by jsonObject.getString("NAME") 
when it returns **false** prompt to add this field.

Maybe use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library? It uses reflection to cast JSON to java classes. You don't need to check if JSON contains specific field or not.

Answer (score 0):

It might be long but you can put each of these "JSONObject.getString("name")" in different try catch and you can define a default value or null in catch.

Answer (score 0):

I use GSON for JSON parsing it's very easy to implement and very effective parsing long and complex responses.